# finding an object by key using lodash

Tags: lodash

I have a json object like this

```
var variable =  {     
  a : { },
  b : { }     
};
```

Using lodash how to get only [{ a: {} }] as result. Basically how to find an object inside list of objects using key.

Comment: Why not just `variable.a`?

Comment: Ya i got that later, ya forgot to update my answer. anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lodash has a `_.get` function.

[documentation](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#get)

The nice thing about `_.get` is that it'll protect you against TypeError exceptions.

In the example below, I am looking for the value of obj.a.b.c. The problem here is that there isn't a property `c` on `obj.a.b` object. This will throw a TypeError. With `_.get`, you can anticipate this and give it a default value if `obj.a.b.c` doesn't exist:

```
"use strict";

var _ = require('lodash');

var obj = {
  a: {
    b: 1
  }
}

var value = _.get(obj, "a.b.c", "this is the default value");

console.log(value);
```

Output:

```
this is the default value
```